# Finding a rewrite rule

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mod-rewrite, codeigniter

I inherited a Codeigniter based PHP application. I'm trying to setup my development workstation to mimic the production system for some development work. An example url would be `http://example.production/start/PAF/paf` the only way I can get it to work on my dev site is `http://example.local/start.php/PAF/paf`. The codeigniter application/config.php uses start as the index_page instead of index.php. On the production system there are no rewrite rules in the httpd.conf or .htaccess. How is it possible that the ".php" is being removed without rewrites? Is there another place I should be looking for the rules?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you look in `httpd.conf`, you should be able to find the Include line(s); the default Apache install uses the following on most systems:

```
Include conf.d/*.conf
```

...but other paths are certainly possible.  Track down the configuration files and see if the rewrite rules you're looking for are in there.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Or, its simply rewriting within the /start/ directory.. ;-)